# Are these spellings the same?

Tags: orthography, arabic

I have virtually zero knowledge on arabic. Different sites have the following sequence of letters of verse 2:201

- [Quran.com](http://quran.com/2/201)
  [image]
- [Quranx.com](http://quranx.com/2.201)
  [image]
- [Tanzil.net](http://tanzil.net/#2:201)
  [image]

Are these highlighted words same or different ?

Comment: The first two are the same: it is a difference in font. The third starts with 'ain in the first to, and alif in the third.

Comment: @ColinFine. You are wrong. The first letter is hamza, not 'ayn. 'ayn would be joined to the following letter.

Comment: Note that there is another try to establish an Arabic Language stack exchange, see http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93710/arabic-language .

Comment: Ah, right. I've never seen hamza on its own. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first and the second one are old scripts, and consequently orthography and spelling, and therefore has the /hamza/ the third one is the simpler one (and in the tanzil website under `Quran` tab you can select the type of text and as you will see it has been set to "simple".

The older text of Quran from the above is probably Medina Mushaf (if I'm not mistaken).

> The Medina Mushaf (officially: Mushaf al-Madinah an-Nabawiyyah, Arabic: مصحف المدينة النبوية) is an authentic copy of the holy quran printed by King Fahad Complex for Printing of the Holy Quran [1]. The Complex publishes the holy quran according to three famous narration, i.e., Hafs, Warsh, and Ad-Duriyy.
>
> http://tanzil.net/wiki/Medina_Mushaf

The Tanzil details on Quran scripts are:

- Simple: Quran text in Imlaaei script (this is the default text).
- Simple Plain: Simple text without special demonstration of Ikhfas and Idghams.
- Simple Minimal: Simple text with minimal number of diacritics and symbols.
- Simple clean: Simple text with no diacritics or symbols.
- Uthmani: Uthmani text, according to Medina Mushaf.
- Uthmani Minimal: Uthmani text with minimal number of diacritics and
  symbols.

Answer (score 2):

They are all the same word. The first two use the old Qur'anic orthography, the third one follows the modern spelling conventions. The pronunciation is the same: /'aatinaa/

The older way to write initial /ʼaa/ is with ʼalif preceded by the diacritic hamza (ءا). In modern Arabic orthography this combination of sounds is written with ʼalif topped by the diacritic madda (آ).